# Check if cookie exists not working with popup

Tags: jquery, cookies

So, I've looked at all the different ways to check if a cookie exists on SO, but none seem to work... any thoughts.

Few Things, it is in a (document).ready function, the plugin is installed and the cookie is stored (tested via alert).

Ive also tried $.cookie('noShow') == null

```
if ($.cookie('noShow') != 'nope') {

setTimeout(function() {
        $("#pop").trigger('click');
    },10);  


}


$("#suNoShow").click(function() {
    $.cookie('noShow', 'nope');
    $(".close-modal").trigger("simpClose");
    //alert($.cookie('noShow'));
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not wrong directly, but you have to set an expiration.

```
var date = new Date();
date.setTime(date.getTime() + 1800000)); // 30 minutes (30 * 60 * 1000)
$.cookie("noShow", "nope", { expires: date });
```

After 30 minutes (in this case) the cookie expires and isn't set.

You only need to check if cookie exists:

```
if (typeof $.cookie("noShow") === 'undefined') {
   // Cookie doesn't exist
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I'm trying to do a session cookie and i thought that by not defining the expiry date, makes it a session cookie

Comment: No, you can't. Only set the expiration date far in the future.

Comment: sorry, im not following so how would you create a session cookie then?

Comment: See my answer, 1800000 is 5 minutes, so increase this nummer to 259200000 (72 * 60 * 60 * 1000) for 72 hours expiration, or 1 year: 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000

Comment: Thanks, you were right, adding the expy date worked -- but i have a follow up if you don't mind -- how would i combine two different cookies?  if (typeof $.cookie("neverShow") === 'undefined' || typeof $.cookie("noShow") === 'undefined'){}

Comment: Use cookies carefully. Set a cookie with specific expiration if 'showed'. While the cookie exists, show nothing. After expiration, you may show again. (b.t.w. Please mark the right answer!) ;-)